# calling WCF service in a Universal application

Tags: c#, wcf, win-universal-app

I am trying to call a WCF service in a windows universal application and apparently you can only call the function "GetMoments" asynchronously. But I can't get the ObservableCollection filled.

```
EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9999/DeliveryService");

NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

DeliveryClient client = new DeliveryClient(binding, address);

Task<ObservableCollection<DeliveryMoment>> moments = client.GetMomentsAsync();
```

moments.Wait() just waits forever and calling moments.Start() is not allowed, this throws an exception. How can I get the collection filled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please test with await/async pattern ? For example:

```
public async void Load()
{
      EndpointAddress address = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:9999/DeliveryService");

      NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);

      DeliveryClient client = new DeliveryClient(binding, address);

      ObservableCollection<DeliveryMoment> moments = await client.GetMomentsAsync();
}
```

Comment: the error has changed into "connection closed by external host". So I guess asynchronous works

Comment: Yes. You should try to call this API in a basic console application and check if you have the same behavior. If this is the case, take a network trace to troubleshoot this issue. A proxy can perhaps close a long running connection.

Comment: apparently WCF for universal apps is not fully implemented yet. You can't create a binding with SecurityMode on and you can't use reliable sessions.